# Does ContentResolver.query escape the arguments, or does it just replace the questionmarks?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Does [`ContentResolver.query`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%29) escape the selection arguments?

For instance, should I manually escape the arguments in `selArgs` before doing something like

```
Cursor c = contentResolver.query(uri, null, "mimetype=?", selArgs, null);
```

or is it done by the `query` method?

Comment: The more I think of it, the more I'm convinced that it *does* escape the arguments properly. AFAIK different DBMS may have different escaping routines. It wouldn't make sense if the `query` contract was bound to a specific DBMS nor would it make sense for me to *know* which DBMS that backed the content resolver.

Answer (score 0):

No. You should do it manually in your content provider.

Source code of the query function:

```
public final Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection,
            String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        IContentProvider provider = acquireProvider(uri);
        if (provider == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            Cursor qCursor = provider.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
            if (qCursor == null) {
                releaseProvider(provider);
                return null;
            }
            // force query execution
            qCursor.getCount();
            long durationMillis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            maybeLogQueryToEventLog(durationMillis, uri, projection, selection, sortOrder);
            // Wrap the cursor object into CursorWrapperInner object
            return new CursorWrapperInner(qCursor, provider);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            releaseProvider(provider);

            // Arbitrary and not worth documenting, as Activity
            // Manager will kill this process shortly anyway.
            return null;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            releaseProvider(provider);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This just delegates the query to another `query` function. See line that starts with `provider.query`. What is the contract of `IContentProvider.query`?

Comment: The query will be delegated to the content provider who can work with the specified uri. Do you have a content provider which extends the android.content.ContentProvider? What is your uri exactly?

Comment: Uhm, I'm interested in the general case, not some specific scenario. (In other words, my question does not involve a specific uri.)

Comment: I use special characters in my database and it is working properly. I don't escape the arguments.

Comment: Ok, (I think I misread your answer previously). So your answer is that client code should *not* bother escaping the selection arguments before passing them to query?

Comment: Exactly. Maybe the system will do it later .. but it is not our job. I use German characters and I had no problem with the escape/unescape.

Comment: those typically dont need escaping.. I was thinking of chars such as ' which can affect where-clauses in SQL for instance.